# Geomesa attribute index in HBase

Tags: geolocation, hbase, geomesa

HBase doesn't support the secondary index, but Geomesa which stores data on top of HBase supports the attribute indexing. How is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeoMesa stores multiple copies of your data, using different HBase tables for each different index.

Edit: there is some documentation [here](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/datastores/index_overview.html) on the different index implementations. In HBase, each index is a separate table.

Comment: Do you know where they have documented it ?